# Getting a #1054 - Unknown column' in 'on clause' when constructing a view when column exists.

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm constructing a sql view with the following code:

```
create or replace view vw_fill_thresholds as
SELECT waypoint_loc.name,
material_typ.description as material, 
fill_thresholds.can_size,
fill_thresholds.threshold,
units.description as unit,
fill_thresholds.post_threshold_cost as ptc,
fill_thresholds.post_threshold_unit_id as ptu
FROM fill_thresholds, fill_locations, material_type, units, waypoint_locations
            left join `waypoint_locations` `waypoint_loc` on(`waypoint_locations`.`id` = `fill_locations`.`waypoint_id`)
            left join `material_type` `material_typ` on(`material_type`.`id` = `fill_locations`.`material`)

WHERE  fill_thresholds.fill_id = fill_locations.id
            and fill_locations.unit_id = units.unit_id
            and fill_thresholds.deleted = 0;
```

My first questions is: 
I don't know if I'm going in the right direction but basically what I want to do is to have fields from materials and wabpoints table using a foreign key that I have in the fill_locations table which is referenced by a key that I have in the fill_threshold table.

and my second question is:

Why do I get an error "`#1054 - Unknown column 'fill_locations.waypoint_id' in 'on clause'` " when I execute that code if I know that waypoint_id exists in the fill_locations table?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: is waypoint_id a column in your table?

Comment: yes in fill_locations table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM fill_thresholds
left join fill_locations on fill_thresholds.fill_id = fill_locations.id 
and fill_thresholds.deleted = 0
left join units on  fill_locations.unit_id = units.unit_id
left join waypoint_locations on `waypoint_locations`.`id` = `fill_locations`.`waypoint_id`
left join `material_type` on `material_type`.`id` = `fill_locations`.`material`
```

Change your `from` conditions to the above, which uses appropriate `join`s. Your query was incorrect syntax-wise. (table used twice)

Comment: thank you vkp for your help! but now I get a similar problem `#1054 - Unknown column 'material_type.id' in 'on clause' ` and I have if on material_type table.

Comment: I think you left a parenthesis at the end of the query, I couldn't edit it because I need to edit more in your answer but it's so brilliant I don't even want to touch it hehe. Thank you so much vkp!

Comment: I have another tiny problem, so, here's the complete view with your help code: http://pastie.org/private/rrubrwhq2uctw96vrglx9g but I have a problem in the last field "fill_thresholds.post_threshold_unit_id" that field contains the id referencing the units table but I would like to grab the description field, just like I did for units.description as unit, so I tried to do the last join but I'm not sure if that's correct. Could you please help me with that one?

Comment: as the units table is already joined,you can select any other column from that table in the select clause

Comment: but I need to select the same column as units. Let me explain you a little bit more: In my fill_thresholds table I have two fields that contain an id from the units table: example 2 and 3. Now, in my units table I have the following fields: id and description. example data: 1 km, 2 miles, 3 yards ,etc. so in my view according to the numbers I have in fill_thresholds it should show miles and yards. Is this possible?

Comment: i am not sure i understood you

Comment: Well, basically I have to do another join because I'm getting the same field as the unit.description in that view. Check out the last line in my paste: http://pastie.org/private/jajvkjj0pn9gw0yayhev8w

Comment: oh i see what you are trying to do..you need not join tha table again. Just add an AND condition where you JOIN units table previously and it would work the same

Comment: Im not sure if I understood: is this what you are trying to say: http://pastie.org/private/2a8rdazdyhxgqnjow88xfg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90382/discussion-between-julio-cesar-and-vkp).